# Java Class Objects Encryption/Decryption and object database

Tags: java, database, encryption, db4o

I have an application ([Amnesia](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsticker/?source=directory)) which lets you create memos/stickers/alarms/Phone Book, and uses db4o (embedded) to store the objects in a .db file.

What I am thinking of doing, is adding an encryption/decryption to protect the data. Let me describe you the process(of what I want to do):

When the app is installed and run for the first time, it will ask for a passphrase. Then it will use that passphrase to encrypt/decrypt the demo data that is created at the first initialization of the database, as well for any entry  that is made later on (yes the first time it is run there is no database. It gets created and populated with demo data).

Every time the user opens the app, it will ask a passphrase from him. The user enters the pass phrase and the app will try to read from the db and decrypts the data. If decryption fails, that means the user entered a "wrong" (different from the first used) passhrase and the app will exit.

What I would like to ask is if this is possible or not? From my search on google, I've only found encryption / decryption of objects like strings, and for other objects the only tutorials were with serialize examples. I do not want to export/import the data from a file (like all the serialization  examples) every time a save or read is done to the database (due to the fact that calls to the database are done very often and it would be un-productive to do so).

What I want is a simple encryption every time an object is written (saved) and a decryption every time an object/class is queried/retrieved from the .db file (embedded db4o).

Can this be done ?

(my other alternative is to use an external file,like a .ini, to store an encrypted user password, and then just check that password with user input each time the app starts, but that is much less secure)

Comment: How about store the `md5` (or other encryption) of the password in the .db?

Comment: @SérgioMichels, MD5 is not encryption algorithm.

Comment: @SérgioMichels, Vash is right, but thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Right, I was thinking about storing the password using some hash function...

Comment: @SérgioMichels , yes , version 7.12 for java, which unfortunately doesnt seem to have that encyption feature ( the one you metnion above seems to be only for the erliest versions of the database )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to encrypt the objects. Encrypt the database.

db4o doesn't include encryption of its own, but you can add it. You need to write a custom [Storage](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/io/Storage.html) implementation that encrypts the data. I think you can do this by writing a subclass of [StorageDecorator](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/io/StorageDecorator.html) that wraps a normal [FileStorage](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/io/FileStorage.html) and adds encryption. You can then use that by [setting it on the FileConfiguration](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/config/FileConfiguration.html#storage%28com.db4o.io.Storage%29).

Comment: so , to see if i understand right, you are suggesting to create the hole .db file encypted with the user initial passphrase, and then to have custom functions that do the decryption of the file at the app startup so that it can be writable/readable ?

Comment: You wouldn't have to decrypt the whole file at startup; you can decrypt blocks on the fly. Your `Storage` implementation is mostly responsible for creating a `Bin` (probably a `BinDecorator`), in which you implement [read](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/io/Bin.html#read%28long,%20byte[],%20int%29) and [write](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.1/java/api/com/db4o/io/Bin.html#write%28long,%20byte[],%20int%29) to decrypt and encrypt the data on its way through.

Answer (score 0):

The initial startup of the aplication will be heavy duty on the CPU.

But if that's what you want this would be the process:

Request password

Fetch everysingle table/rows into objects, encrypt it then update it in the db.

As to Encryption/Decryption,
Personally would sugest AES 128 for cross platform compatibility in case you're going for OS independant.

[Java SUN AES](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html)

Comment: actually, there are no tables/rows . db4o is by itself a database for objects, so every thing stored in it is an object. So my most basic question was how to encrypt objects other than strings.(for example hot to encypt an object of MEMO class) . Thanks dor the quick reply and for the AES suggestion though :)

Comment: Convert Object to  Byte[] then encrypt it seems a good solution

Comment: Check out Serialization
[Java Sun Serialization](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)